# Does SSHFS store files on the local machine when loading files?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, sshfs

My company wants to use SSHFS to mount a directory from a secure remote server. An application on the local (client) machine needs to access files to read and edit their content (read/write). However, our business requires us to never have the files stored locally on the client machine. We searched the SSHFS documentation, but we couldn't figure this out: When an application access a remote file, is the file stored locally somewhere on hard disk? If so, where would those files reside when they're accessed by an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*sshfs* acts as a client for the SFTP protocol, which supports partial file operations. That is, the client doesn't need to retrieve the whole file (like FTP would) – for example, if an application issues seek(1024) followed by read(256), then *sshfs* only needs to retrieve the 256 bytes requested.

All of that means that the file *does not need* to be stored locally anywhere at all (except as far as the application itself has read its data into memory). The sshfs client can just throw away operation results as soon as it is done with them.

Similarly, if you open a `sftp://` URL in a GNOME app, that uses the "GVFS" SFTP client which also supports passing individual operations directly between the application and the server, so it doesn't have to cache the file locally at all.

---

But note that not all SFTP clients can work this way. For example, KDE Dolphin also supports `sftp://` URLs through the KIO client, which until last month *did not* support partial operations – it would always download the entire file to somewhere under `~/.cache/` before giving it to the app. (AFAIK, this was finally solved in the very latest release together with the addition of kio-fuse.)

The SFTP clients built into text editors also tend to use local copies, e.g. Vim's netrw downloads the file to `/tmp` and uploads it back every time.